# Scraping Javascript with Python

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Note: I am a newb. This will be readily evident in the question at hand.

I am needing to scrape the wait times from the following websites:

https://www.floridahospital.com/locations/er-wait-times

http://www.centura.org/erwait

I have tried scraping via XPath with lmxml and via DOM with BeautifulSoup. Someone told me that, because these values don't load in the source code, they are being rendered with Javascript. So, I've researched scraping JS elements with Python.

To me, it looks like Selenium would be overkill as I don't have to click on anything - the content loads, just not directly in the HTML that I can grab. PhantomJS requires writing in JS, and I've read people have had issues porting that to AWS or non-GUI servers.

I've seen Ghost.py and that looks like it's compatibly with BS4, so might be easiest.

What would the easiest way to grab these wait times? Are they being loaded with JS?

Also, if your answer would confuse a toddler, it would likely me - so please keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for executing the JavaScript.

- For the first site, just fetch their JSON files, they're easy to parse: https://www.floridahospital.com/eddoor2doc/json
- For the second site, pull the set of documents (one per hospital): https://rss.mycenturahealth.org/edwaittime/edwait.aspx?facilitycode=av

Comment: How did you know the first site would have a JSON output link somewhere? For the second, I can go to each RSS page but it still produces the same issue, where I cannot scrape the tag ad produce a result. What does "pull set of documents" mean? Like I said: newb.

Comment: It _must_ load the data from somewhere, and JSON is a very common way of doing so. To find the URL, either read through all their code or just fire Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug and monitor which files get loaded during refreshing the page. For the second site: With set of documents I mean that each hospital has its data under a URL like this, just the facilitycode is different.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple task, I'd **still** recommend [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)/[CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/)

Porting it is usually simply a matter of creating a dummy display with [xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)

I've had some experience with CasperJS, and I found it very enjoyable before moving on to [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) as my needs changed and a complete framework was required (maybe give that a try?)